# No result for SPARQL query at dbpedia.org

Tags: syntax, sparql, dbpedia

I'm trying to get the values "6.25" and "$6.25-7.6 billion" with this query on [dbpedia](http://dbpedia.org/sparql) from [Prince of Lichtenstein Foundation](http://dbpedia.org/page/Prince_of_Liechtenstein_Foundation)

```
SELECT ?Value1 ?Value2 WHERE {
?Value1 dbpedia-owl:assetUnderManagement category:Prince_of_Liechtenstein_Foundation.
?Value2 <http://dbpedia.org/property/aum> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Prince_of_Liechtenstein_Foundation>.
}
```

Do I have an error in the code? Or am I using a wrong syntax?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is correct, but the direction is wrong.

```
SELECT distinct * WHERE {
dbpedia:Prince_of_Liechtenstein_Foundation dbpedia-owl:assetUnderManagement ?value1.
dbpedia:Prince_of_Liechtenstein_Foundation dbpprop:aum ?value2.

}
```